# How to make two "intent" in android studio code not processing at the same time?

Tags: java, android

In the code below (log in code), I have one button that if it clicked, it will start two intent. One intent is to use to open **A** class and the other is to use to send a string value to **B** class. But when the button clicked, the second intent not just sending the string value but also open the **B** class. The code supposedly to just send the string value to **B** class and open **A** class.

How to fix this?

```
package com.example.project;

public class login extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseReference reff;
EditText kode, pass;
Button masuk;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    kode = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kode);
    pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
    masuk = (Button)findViewById(R.id.masuk);

    masuk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(kode.getText().toString()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(pass.getText().toString())){
                Toast.makeText(login.this, "isi kode alat atau password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            else {
                final String value = kode.getText().toString().trim();
                reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(value);

                final String password = pass.getText().toString().trim();

                // Read from the database
                reff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                        // whenever data at this location is updated.
                        String passin = dataSnapshot.child("pass").getValue().toString();

                        if (passin.equals(password)){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(login.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

                            Intent send = new Intent(login.this, addmember.class);
                            send.putExtra("kode", value);
                            startActivity(send);
                        }

                        else if(!passin.equals(password)){
                            Toast.makeText(login.this, "password salah", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                        // Failed to read value
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If youo dont want to open any activity, remove the `startActivity` code, but i am not sure why you are trying to open one activity and pass value to other activity, check if it helps

Comment: it is impossible to open multiple activity at once. So try flow activity. login -> MainActivity -> addmember

Comment: Start activity always opens activity, In your case, you have called it two times. so A and B  both activity will be launched. If you want to pass data to existing opened Activity B you can use LocalBroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you can't start activity because you are trying to start two activities at same time. This is not possible and if possible this approach is not too good. In safe side, you can use EventBus library that used for pushing event as data and subscriber that receive that data. This is the right way to do what you want here.